# How to split the string into string and integer in java?

Tags: java, string, split, numbers, number-formatting

I have the `String a="abcd1234"` and I want to split this into `String b="abcd"` and `Int c=1234`. This Split code should apply for all king of input like `ab123456` and `acff432` and so on. How to split this kind of Strings. Is it possible?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You could try to split on a regular expression like `(?<=\D)(?=\d)`. Try this one:

```
String str = "abcd1234";
String[] part = str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)");
System.out.println(part[0]);
System.out.println(part[1]);
```

will output

```
abcd
1234
```

You might parse the digit String to Integer with `Integer.parseInt(part[1])`.

Comment: `\D` matches all non-digit characters, while `\d` matches all digit characters. `?<=` is a positive lookbehind (so everything before the current position is asserted to be a non-digit character), `?=` is a positive lookahead (so everything after the current position is asserted as a digit). Does this help?

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap this regex will not work if a string like "ABC123DEF567".

Comment: @MohitTyagi That's correct, but this is a total different question than the OP had. If you want to find the correct regex, try to play around a little bit with https://github.com/gskinner/regexr.

Comment: How will we separate if we have , for example a,1,g,4,5,12,jh,49,mn?

Answer (score 3):

Use a regular expression:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-z]+)([0-9]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (!m.find())
{ 
  // handle bad string
}
String s = m.group(1);
int i = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2));
```

I haven't compiled this, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the ans!

Answer (score 3):

You can do the next:

1. Split by a regex like `split("(?=\\d)(?<!\\d)")`
2. You have an array of strings with that and  you only have to parse it.

Comment: "(?=\\d)(?<!\\d)" please explain this

Answer (score 1):

```
String st = "abcd1234";
String st1=st.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
String st2=st.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
System.out.println("String b = "+st1);
System.out.println("Int c = "+st2);
```

Output

```
String b = abcd
Int c = 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force solution.

```
String a = "abcd1234";
int i;
for(i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
    char c = a.charAt(i);
    if( '0' <= c && c <= '9' )
        break;
}
String alphaPart = a.substring(0, i);
String numberPart = a.substring(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... s) throws Exception {
        Pattern VALID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z])+|[0-9]*");
    List<String> chunks = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher matcher = VALID_PATTERN.matcher("ab1458");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        chunks.add( matcher.group() );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're confusing your character class brackets [] with parentheses ().

Comment: @Javier: The patterns says: Any case letters and/or numbers

Comment: @Ravi: Sorry, I did not get you.

Comment: Your quantifier + should have been after () like `([A-Z]|[a-z])+` and letters could also have been clubbed together like [a-zA-Z]. First issue is a downright error. The second one just works better.

Comment: Actually, your regex just won't work. You have a `|` pipe before [0-9]+ making an OR between letters and numbers. You should withdraw this as a solution or fix it after testing properly.

Comment: @Ravi: Without a pipe it would not strip the string into letters and digits. For the code above, without pipe, the ArrayList would just get one element, ab1458. By the way I edited it to work if the string is all aphabets

Comment: With a pipe regex would make a match on just "abc" or just "123" as well. To split "abc123" you would do `if(m.find()) { System.out.println("Letters="+m.group(1)+" Numbers="+m.group(2));}` where the regex without a pipe could be `(\w+)(\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

Use regex **"[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])"** to split the sting by alphabets and numbers.

for e.g.

```
String str = "ABC123DEF456";
```

Then the output by using this regex will be :

> ABC
> 123
> DEF
> 456

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question already has an accepted answer. Please provide more explanation to show how your answer is perhaps better or different than those already provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can add some delimiter characters [`⦀`](https://unicode-table.com/en/2980/) to each group of symbols, and then split the string around those delimiters:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] arr = {
            split("abcd1234", "\u2980"),
            split("ab123456", "\u2980"),
            split("acff432", "\u2980")};

    Arrays.stream(arr)
            .map(Arrays::toString)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    // [abcd, 1234]
    // [ab, 123456]
    // [acff, 432]
}
```

```java
private static String[] split(String str, String delimiter) {
    return str
            // add delimiter characters
            // to non-empty sequences
            // of numeric characters
            // and non-numeric characters
            .replaceAll("(\\d+|\\D+)", "$1" + delimiter)
            // split the string around
            // delimiter characters
            .split(delimiter, 0);
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to split a string delimited on if substring can be casted as an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65334063/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
String input_string = "asdf1234";
String string_output=input_string.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
int number_output=Integer.parseInt(input_string.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
System.out.println("string_output = "+string_output);
System.out.println("number_output = "+number_output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String a = "a1j2a3i4";
    int i;
    String str1="";
    String str2="";
    for(i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
             char c = a.charAt(i);
                if( '0' <= c && c <= '9' )
                         str1=str1+c;
                if( 'a' <= c && c <= 'z' )
                         str2=str2+c;
       }
   System.out.println(str1);
   System.out.println(str2);
   }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).